# Android App 2 Different Actions

Tags: android

I want to know if it's possible to have 2 different actions when starting an app.
Like when you go to all programs and select your app you open the app 
and if you open the app from the quick selection(I'm not sure if it's called this but a screen like this : 
 
[image]

then it runs some code and shows me a Toast.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please rephrase your question.  I think I know what you mean, but I'm not entirely sure.  I'd rather not give an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You register "intent filters" with Android in your manifest.xml.  The "main" intent filter is the one that the launcher uses, and the only one the launcher uses, to start your app.  So, if you start your app via the launcher, it will always start via the Activity associated with the "main" intent.

You can also register other intent filters e.g. send email.  When a user is using a 3rd party app and selects "Send email", if Android has exactly one intent registered from an app that says "I can do that", it is launched via that intent.  If more than one app has registered intents for "send email", Android displays the chooser you have shown in your question.  If more than one app has registered intents for "send email", and the user has set an app to be the default app for the intent (hence the "use by default" checkbox), Android launches that app via the intent.

Start by reading about intent filters here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, this helped me but I don't get it to work entirely as how I want it. What it is doing now is still starting the app. I managed to close it with System.Exit(0);. But that's not really clean code. Since I start the app and then close the app. What I want is when I click on the app that it just executes some code and shows me a Toast whether it succeeded, failed or error(catch). Is that possible?